How can I set these options programmatically in a Jenkins multi-branch pipeline?
I have several multi-branch pipeline jobs and I need to set this in all of them. I can point-and-click I know, but how can I set them programmatically in the Jenkins script console? They're the Branch Sources -> Behaviors block of the job configuration page. I know how to search all the jobs that I need, just want the particular code for these settings. Thanks!


You have to use Job DSL and generate your jobs using a seed job like here

What is your GIT SCM source (Git, Bitbucket, GitHub)?

@NoamHelmer in my case it’s Bitbucket. Thanks

You can use the groovy api in the script console to configure all proprieties of your job.
Assuming your job already exists you can use something like this:
import com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.*
import com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.DefaultOrphanedItemStrategy
import jenkins.branch.*
import jenkins.plugins.git.*
import jenkins.plugins.git.traits.*
import jenkins.scm.impl.trait.*
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.*
import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.*
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.triggers.*

def jobName = "my_job_name"
def job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobName, WorkflowMultiBranchProject)

// Initiate the SCM source with the repository URL
def source = new GitSCMSource("my_repo_url")
// Set the Git credentials ID
source.credentialsId = "my_id"
// Set the Behaviors (Traits)
source.setTraits([
        new BranchDiscoveryTrait(), // Discover Branches
        new TagDiscoveryTrait(), // Discover Tags
        new WildcardSCMHeadFilterTrait("master feature/* patch/*","staging"), // Filter by name (with wildcards)
        new RegexSCMHeadFilterTrait(''), // Filter by name (with regular expression)
])

// Set the source
job.setSourcesList([new BranchSource(source)])

// Set other job parameters
job.setDescription("")
job.setDisplayName(jobName)
job.setOrphanedItemStrategy(new DefaultOrphanedItemStrategy(true, "10", "10"))

// Save the Job
job.save()

For more available traits see the following API
If you also want to configure the strategies you can see an example here
